# Pandas rearrange groupby objects ( many-to-many)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a many-to-many dataframe that look something like this, where and id could have contains multiple lands, and a land could too contains multiple ids:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'land': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'area': [123, 234, 123, 23, 342, 12],
    'info': ['Im', 'never', 'gonna', 'give', 'you', 'up']
})
```

Eventually I'm joining this to GIS and I need to rearrange data to one-to-one format grouping by land.

My expected output could be like this:
*( I too struggle to get this to print out groupby object. I want the **full data** instead of using count() or size(), but it will only return pandas.groupbyObject.)*

|  |  | area | info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| land | id |  |  |
| A | a | 123 | Im |
|  | b | 123 | gonna |
|  | c | 23 | give |
| B | a | 234 | never |
|  | c | 342 | you |
| C | c | 12 | up |

...and to merge the data to make it one-on-one: *(just an example output format. Could be your own readable way as long as that one lands can show all ids and information properly)*

| land | id | area | info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.a ; 2.b ; 3.c | a:123 ; b:123 ; c:23 | a:'Im' ; b:'gonna' ; c:'give' |
| B | 1.a ; 2.c | a:234 ; c:342 | a:'never' ; c:'you' |
| C | c | 12 | 'up' |

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is simple enough. Just `set_index` + `sort_index`:

```
option1 = t.set_index(['land','id']).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
         area   info
land id             
A    a    123     Im
     b    123  gonna
     c     23   give
B    a    234  never
     c    342    you
C    c     12     up
```

Option 2 is a bit tricky. One way is to use `groupby.apply` where you apply a custom function that combines `id`s with `area` and `info` for each `land`:

```
def combine(x):
    return '; '.join(f'{i}:{j}' for i,j in x) if len(x) > 1 else f'{x[0][1]}'

tmp = t.groupby('land').apply(lambda x: [combine(list(enumerate(x['id'], 1))),
                                         combine(x[['id','area']].to_numpy()),
                                         combine(x[['id','info']].to_numpy())])

option2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp.tolist(), index=tmp.index, columns=['id','area','info'])
```

Output:

```
                 id                area                   info
land                                                          
A     1:a; 2:b; 3:c  a:123; b:123; c:23  a:Im; b:gonna; c:give
B          1:a; 2:c        a:234; c:342         a:never; c:you
C                 c                  12                     up
```